# Google Analytics API pagination missing records

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We have a system that queries GA API for a large amount of tokens, mostly for website visits and sessions data.

We have noticed lately that we're getting weird results while querying the API - specifically we're seeing missing records from the result set. Even more specifically, it looks like when we have a few pages of rows, when starting the next page the results would "skip" the beginning of the page.

This behavior is not consistent - each run a different set of sites/tokens would display this bug, and when I tried debugging the code manually I've never encountered this behavior.

At first I thought the problem was with our code, maybe some sort of race condition or shared memory, but it seems like the problem is with the API access itself - this is because I've checked the TotalResults property that is returned with the query, and when this bug happens it shows less rows in total than the amount I see when I query manually.

For example, we'd query for a site with date and country dimensions, and the rows logged would be:

```
domain | year | month | day | country | metrics
-----------------------------------------------
X.com 2017 09 22 IT ..... // metrics
// finished result page
X.com 2017 09 24 BW ..... // metrics
....
Total rows - 1295
```

when we ran the same code again, we got rows with 2017-09-23 values for this site, and total rows - 1368

Is this a bug in the API? Or maybe in the way we access it? I haven't found a mention of such a problem.

EDIT: I've added the API call method code we use.

```
private GaDataFlat GetDataV3(string type, string profileID,
                List<Metric> v4metrics, List<MetricFilterClause> v4metricFilters,
                List<Dimension> v4dimensions, List<DimensionFilterClause> v4dimensionFilters,
                List<OrderBy> v4sorting, DateTime start, DateTime end, int maxResults)
    {
        List<string> metrics = (v4metrics == null ? null : v4metrics.Select(x => x.Expression).ToList());
        List<string> dimensions = (v4dimensions == null ? null : v4dimensions.Select(x => x.Name).ToList());
        List<string> sorting = (v4sorting == null ? null : v4sorting.Select(x => x.FieldName).ToList());
        List<string> filters = (v4dimensionFilters == null ? null : v4dimensionFilters.Select(x => deconstructFilter(x)).ToList());

        return ExponentialBackoff.Go(() =>
        {
            var gaData = new GaDataFlat { DataTable = new DataTable() };

            DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:" + profileID,
                start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), String.Join(",", metrics));

                //Set the user Quota to not have concurrent limitiation 
                request.QuotaUser = profileID + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            if (dimensions != null)
            {
                request.Dimensions = string.Join(",", dimensions);
            }

            if (filters != null)
            {
                request.Filters = string.Join(";", filters);
            }

            if (sorting != null)
            {
                request.Sort = "-" + string.Join(";-", sorting);
            }

            request.SamplingLevel = DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest.SamplingLevelEnum.HIGHERPRECISION;

            bool hasNext;
            int rowCount = 0;
            int iteration = 0;
            do
            {
                iteration++;
                MetricsProvider.Counter("ga.iteration", 1, "type:" + type);
                if (iteration > 100)
                {
                    string error = "Too many iterations ";
                    LogFacade.Fatal(error);
                    throw new Exception(error);
                }

                if (!counter.IncrementAndCheckAvailablility(Constants.APIS.GA))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Daily Limit Exceeded - counter");
                    throw new QuotaExceededException();
                }

                GaData DataList = request.Execute();

                gaData.SampleSize = DataList.SampleSize;
                gaData.SampleSpace = DataList.SampleSpace;


                if (DataList.Rows != null)
                {
                    if (gaData.DataTable.Columns.Count == 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < DataList.ColumnHeaders.Count; j++)
                        {
                            gaData.DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn
                            {
                                ColumnName = DataList.ColumnHeaders[j].Name
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var row in DataList.Rows.ToList())
                    {
                        var reportRow = new List<object>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < DataList.ColumnHeaders.Count; j++)
                        {
                            reportRow.Add(row[j]);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(":", v4dimensionFilters.SelectMany(f => f.Filters.SelectMany(inner => inner.Expressions))) + "," +
                            string.Join(",", reportRow.Select(cell => cell.ToString())));

                        gaData.DataTable.Rows.Add(reportRow.ToArray());
                    }

                    rowCount += DataList.Rows.Count;
                    request.StartIndex = rowCount;
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(":", v4dimensionFilters.SelectMany(f => f.Filters.SelectMany(inner => inner.Expressions))) + ", next page starts " + request.StartIndex);
                    hasNext = rowCount < DataList.TotalResults;
                }
                else
                {
                    hasNext = false;
                }
            } while (hasNext && (maxResults == 0 || rowCount < maxResults));

            return gaData;
        }, type, "GetData " + profileID + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
```

EDIT: The filter we use is consistent - for example, we want to get desktop visits for website x.com, the filter would be:

```
ga:hostname=~x\.com(\/|)$;ga:deviceCategory==desktop
```

Comment: please include your code.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added the API call, however I can't add the call itself, as it involves a token and other information I would rather not post here.

Comment: you should consider using pagestreamer.   I have an example of it for google drive https://www.daimto.com/pagination-google-net-client-library/  you will have to alter it for analytics.  Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: I changed the code to incorporate the pagestreamer - and I've encountered the problem again, even while debugging.

Comment: try it without your filter.   I would bet its something with the filter.  you can also try testing here https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: I've ran the same query in a loop, and printed the number of total rows. It returned less rows on the first run, and then the correct amount. If the problem was with the filter, it wouldn't give different results for multiple runs of the same query, no?

Comment: That would also depend upon what days you are requesting data for.   If you are doing it for today or yesterday yes there can come more rows as data has not completed processing for 24 - 72 hours.  Did you try testing in query exporer

Comment: I queried for September - 1.9 - 30.9. I've tried with the query explorer, and it return what I expected - all rows . Problem with that is that I can't choose which token to use, I can only see my own account.